# What are the main causes for eyeball becoming too long or short in myopia and hyperopia?

Tags: optics, vision, biology

myopia and hypeopia occur due to change in eye ball size or lack in cilliary muscle ability to accomodate. \n\n

But why in lasik laser operation , the one's cornea shape is changed rather than acting on cilliary muscles or somehow fixing the size of eyeball?\n\n

And why does the eyeball become larger or smaller? Does it happen due to external injury or some internal mechanism? What makes the eyeball change it size?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you are describing *axial* myopia, indeed caused by a change in the eyeball shape. In some cases, the cornea itself maybe the problem. But your question is still valid for axial myopia and I will try to answer.

Regarding the laser operation acting on the cornea, it is the same as wearing glasses or contact lenses: You adjust the (innocent) lens (the refracting and focusing machinery of the eye) to offset the disabling defect of the (guilty) eyeball. To put it in physics terms:

You have a lens (the refracting and focusing machinery of the eye, which includes the cornea) positioned perfectly in front of a screen (the retina), so that the focal point of the lens lies on the screen. Perfect vision.

Now for some reason the screen is shifted backwards or forwards. (That's the eyeball muscles misbehaving.) You want to shift the screen back to its original position, but you cannot (muscles won't obey, surgical procedure difficult,...) So you operate on the lens (the refractive machinery) and change its focal point so that it lies on the newly positioned screen.

More on the underlying mechanisms of myopia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-sightedness#Mechanism

Comment: mirkastath, I've had Lasik, and I can verify that most of the focusing power of the eye comes from the cornea, while the lens does adjustments to that focusing power.  In Lasik surgery, the curvature of the cornea is changed, but the lens of the eye is unaffected.

Comment: I think we are saying the same. Lens in my answer is the optical analogue of the cornea, not the lens of the eye.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer for clarity.